# importing CSV file in Google cloud sql only shows 1 row

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to import a csv file that contains 5 columns and 100 rows. When I open the terminal and type SELECT * FROM cmc2 it only shows 1 row.

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM cmc2;
+--------------------------------+-------+------------+--------------------+--------+
| alt_name                       | price | market_cap | circulating_supply | volume |
+--------------------------------+-------+------------+--------------------+--------+
| Alt coin name;Price;Market cap |   554 |        714 |                630 |   NULL |
+--------------------------------+-------+------------+--------------------+--------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

this is my table that i created:

```
mysql> create table cmc2 (alt_name varchar(30), price int(20), market_cap int(20), circulating_supply int(20), volume int(20));
```

Comment: It looks like the CSV file that you imported had a different separator, looks strange to have "Alt coin name;Price;Market cap" in that column. Is that expected? Can you share a sample of the CSV file that you imported?

Comment: I got the 100 rows now, but the problem is the separator. The CSV file uses semicolon as a delimiter. Do you know how I can read this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/import-export/importing) "CSV files must have one line for each row of data and have comma-separated fields." So you should replace the semicolons in your file with commas.

This should be an easy task if you have a tool like Word, Excel, etc... Where you can do a search (Control + F) and select replace with... then import the CSV file with the required separator